# Using npregress to compute local regressions at specific points (as is possible with kernmeans)

Tags: regression, stata

I have some code that uses the user-defined command `kernmean`, which computes kernel means for bivariate regression. The code is:

```
kernmean y x if cond_a==1 & cond_b=1 & cond_c>cond_d, order(1) at(z) generate(newvar) epan bw(5)
```

Where the command estimates a local kernel mean at each value of variable z using the Epanechnikov kernel and a bandwidth of 5 for all observations satisfying the various conditions.

I need to include controls in the regression and cannot do this using the user-defined command `kernmean`. Instead I want to use the Stata command `npregress`. The code I have so far is:

```
npregress kernel y x1 x2 if if cond_a==1 & cond_b=1 & cond_c>cond_d, kernel(ep) predict(newvar1 newvar2 newvar3) bwidth(5 5 5 5, copy)
```

However, this does not estimate the mean at each value of variable z.

Is there a way to include such an option in the `npregress` command, or is there another command that could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

As you say it doesn't provide a built-in option to compute kernel means at each value of a specific variable such as the kernmean function. Here’s a workaround using some Stata commands.

So, to compute kernel means at each value of variable z while also including control variables in your regression:

stata

```
// Step 1: Compute the kernel mean at each value of z
kernmean newvar_y newvar_x y x if cond_a == 1 & cond_b == 1 & cond_c > cond_d, ///
    order(1) at(z) generate(kernel_mean) epan bw(5)

// Step 2: Run the regression with control variables
regress y x1 x2 control1 control2 ... if cond_a == 1 & cond_b == 1 & cond_c > cond_d

// Step 3: Merge the kernel means back into the dataset
merge 1:1 z using your_dataset, keep(match) nogen
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! My issue is that the kernmean function will only take two variables before the if statement in your step 1 above.

Comment: Also for clarity: x2 in the example in my post is the control I want to add